# Invalid value: null used for required field: \"null\", schema type: STRING\n\tat

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

We're upgrading to Confluent Platform 5.5.2, after upgrading, one of our Kafka JDBC Sink Connector (not all) starts getting the issue with the error log below

`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:472)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:204)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.SchemaBuilderException: Invalid default value\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder.defaultValue(SchemaBuilder.java:131)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1812)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1567)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1687)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1543)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectData(AvroData.java:1226)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:108)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid value: null used for required field: \"null\", schema type: STRING\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.ConnectSchema.validateValue(ConnectSchema.java:220)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.ConnectSchema.validateValue(ConnectSchema.java:213)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder.defaultValue(SchemaBuilder.java:129)\n\t... 23 more\n`

Any one got the same issue and already resolved it?

We haven't upgraded Schema Registry to newer version (it's still using 5.0.0 version), upgrading Schema Registry might help to resolve the issue?

Update:

- We did upgrade Schema Registry to the same Confluent Platform version, but the error still be happening.

Fixed:

- I have figured out the root cause was there is a field in my AVRO schema has `type` not include `"null"` value. After adding `"null"` value into `type` the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Any solution? I just met the same exception on confluent-6.0.0.

Comment: @felicienb, no still waiting for a response from other

Answer (score 2):

Your error is likely to be an inconsistency in the avro schema of one of your topics at the `default` field.
Check that you never set a `"default": null` when the `type` of your field does not allow `null`.

Ex:

**BAD** field:

```
{
    "default": null,
    "name": "field_name",
    "type": "string"
}
```

**GOOD** field :

```
{
    "name": "field_name",
    "type": "string"
}
```

Or, **GOOD** field :

```
{
    "default": null,
    "name": "field_name",
    "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks I figured out one of field in my AVRO schema has no "null" case in "type". The issue has been fixed after adding "null" into `type`

Comment: Confirmed this is the correct solution for resolving the issue in my post. Thank you!

Comment: I am using exactly what's there in "GOOD field" with null in default and type. But it doesn't work. Both the cases - passing optional field and skipping optional field from json - none of them works. I confirmed this seeing some more threads / questions and bugs - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2160 / https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2447. Wondering how did this work for you?